# How and when "pinyin" becomes an English word, or not yet? How to tell?

Tags: word-usage

How and when "pinyin" became an English word, or not yet? How to tell?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Why do you believe it is (or might be) an English word? Did you look in a dictionary?

Comment: Late 1970's? NGrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pinyin&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpinyin%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPinyin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpinyin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPINYIN%3B%2Cc0

Comment: OED's first citation is from *McGraw-Hill Mod. Chinese-Eng. Dict, **1963***. As to *how*, they say it's *Chinese **pīnyīn** < **pīn** to put together + **yīn** sound. For earlier use of the Chinese word in an English context compare: **1959** W. Simon Chinese Radicals & Phonetics rev. ed. p432   A further Scheme, apparently to be regarded as final,..on 11th February 1958 was approved by the Fifth Session of the First National People's Congress. Its Chinese name is **Hanyu-Pinyin-Fang'an** (Chinese Language Spelling Scheme).*

Comment: @ColleenV in Google translation, "pinyin" as English gives the correct Chinese characters.

Comment: Seems like Google translates it successfully either way: https://translate.google.com/#en/zh-CN/pinyin   OR https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E6%8B%BC%E9%9F%B3

Comment: Thank you for clarifying PdotWang. Understanding why you are asking the question can help us answer it more completely.

Answer (score 1):

[Etymonline claims 1963](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pinyin&allowed_in_frame=0):

*pinyin (n.) system of Romanized spelling for Chinese, 1963, from Chinese pinyin "to spell, to combine sounds into syllables," from pin "put together" + yin "sound, tone." Adopted officially by the People's Republic of China in 1958. Outside China gradually superseding the 19c. Wade-Giles system (Mao Tse-tung is Wade-Giles, Mao Zedong is pinyin).*

Comment: It's interesting to me that it's not capitalized. Shouldn't it be as the proper name of a system?

Comment: I'm assuming it's *not* a proper name.  It's just a compound of two common nouns.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, just odd given the definition and that Romaji is typically capitalized when I see it. Actually looking at more examples, I'm thinking it shouldn't be capitalized. Back when I do more research

Answer (score -1):

No, I do not consider *pinyin* to be an English word.

You will know that *pinyin* has become an English word when you see native speakers doing all of the following:

- deriving other words from *pinyin* (by using English prefixes and suffixes),
- neither underlining "pinyin", nor putting it in quotes, nor *italicizing* it.
- not feeling the need to define the word shortly before or after using it for the first time.

Contrary to [catiya](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/16318)'s comment, it is easy to find native speakers using esoteric words without immediately defining the terms.  And these words have related words that differ only in prefixes and suffixes.  For example:

- esoteric, esoterica
- niche, niches (Note that the American English version of the word is [pronounced differently](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/neesh-or-nitch) from the French version, *niche*.  The French version is indicated by italicization.)
- viscous, inviscid, viscosity
- difference, differential, differentiable, differentiability

Comment: By that argument, half of the words used (in English) would not be English words... a word being rare and not commonly recognized doesn't mean it isn't a word... it just means it has a niche audience.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't consider any of those words you just listed to be particularly esoteric. I'll just put on my shakos and march on out of here, though. No need for argument.

Comment: 'niche' Eng is pronounced differently? Only by the illiterate. It doesn't rhyme with rich.

Comment: @Tetsujin Actually, niche has been anglicized and it is fairly common for educated people to pronounce it _nitch_ without anyone blinking an eye. Unless someone is of course itching to start the toe-may-toe / toe-mah-toe debate. I still say nouveau riche ala Français though :) Most dictionaries list both pronunciations, with _nitch_ predominate when you restrict your search to AmE.